# How to bind to a dependency property already bound ? (Binding chain)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, binding

I have 3 elements :

- My MainWindow
- UserControlA containing UserControlB
- UserControlB contained by UserControlA

My UserControlB is doing a job on an image and has a DependencyProperty declared :

```
    public ImageSource Source
    {
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        get { return GetValue(SourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(UserControlB));
```

And the image a work on in the UserControlB is bound to this dependency :

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Source}" />
```

With a relative DataContext on the UserControl:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Then comes the UserControlA. If I use the UserControlB and set Source property direclty, everything just work fine.
But, my UserControlA has also a Dependency Property which set the ImageSource :

```
    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return GetValue(SourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(UserControlA));
```

And it is also bound by the same way :

```
<my:UserControlB Source="{Binding Path=Source}" />
```

With also a relative DataContext on the UserControl :

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

And now in my MainWindow, I have my UserControlA which must display my UserControlB :

```
<my:UserControlA Source="/Project;component/Images/090607153529_49.jpg" />
```

The problem : it doesn't work.

I tried to put a simple image bound to the Source in the UserControlA : it works.
I tried to set the Source of the UserControlB manually in the UserControlA : it works.
I tried to tell the UserControlA to notify when the property is changed :

```
Source="{Binding Path=Source, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

it doesn't work.

So, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761531/chain-of-databinding , there is a workaround