# Why does the ComboBox.SelectedValue DataBinding context gets cleared when BindingList changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have some logic in the business layer that limits the ComboBox options according to inputs, so I need to change the values in the underlying BindingList. But when the list gets changed, the two-way binding becomes one-way from UI to Entity only.

```
_mComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _mEntity, "WifeCount");
```

Full code with problem in the assign button click handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EnumDataBinding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox _mComboBox = new ComboBox();
        Button _mCheckButton = new Button();
        Button _mAssignButton = new Button();

        BindingList<OptionValue> _mBindingList = new BindingList<OptionValue>();
        List<OptionValue> _mCacheList = new List<OptionValue>();

        Entity _mEntity = new Entity();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // create a reset button
            _mCheckButton.Size = new Size(100, 30);
            _mCheckButton.Text = "Check";
            _mCheckButton.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            _mCheckButton.Click += new EventHandler(_mCheck_Click);

            // create assignment button
            _mAssignButton.Size = new Size(100, 30);
            _mAssignButton.Text = "Assign";
            _mAssignButton.Location = new Point(100, 135);
            _mAssignButton.Click += new EventHandler(_mAssignButton_Click);

            // create a combo box
            _mComboBox = new ComboBox();
            _mComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 30);
            _mComboBox.Location = new Point(100, 200);

            this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
                _mComboBox,
                _mCheckButton,
                _mAssignButton
            });

            // fill the bindinglist
            _mBindingList.Add(new OptionValue("One", 1M));
            _mBindingList.Add(new OptionValue("Two", 2M));
            _mBindingList.Add(new OptionValue("Three", 3M));

            _mCacheList.Add(new OptionValue("One", 1M));
            _mCacheList.Add(new OptionValue("Two", 2M));
            _mCacheList.Add(new OptionValue("Three", 3M));
        }

        void _mAssignButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // reset options
            _mBindingList.Clear();
            foreach (var o in _mCacheList)
                _mBindingList.Add(o);

            // EXPECTED: Update ComboBox.SelectedValue and ComboBox.Text
            // RESULT: Does not happen.
            _mEntity.WifeCount = 3M;

            this.Text = string.Format("SelectedValue: {0}; WifeCount: {1}", _mComboBox.SelectedValue, _mEntity.WifeCount);
        }

        private void PrepareComboBox(ComboBox combobox, BindingList<OptionValue> list)
        {
            combobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            combobox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            combobox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            combobox.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = list };
            combobox.DisplayMember = "Display";
            combobox.ValueMember = "Value";
            combobox.Text = string.Empty;
            combobox.SelectedText = string.Empty;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            // combo box datasource binding
            PrepareComboBox(_mComboBox, _mBindingList);

            // entity data binding
            _mComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _mEntity, "WifeCount", false);

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        void _mCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = string.Format("SelectedValue: {0}; WifeCount: {1}", _mComboBox.SelectedValue, _mEntity.WifeCount);
        }
    }

    public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        decimal _mWifeCount;

        public decimal WifeCount { get { return _mWifeCount; } set { _mWifeCount = value; OnPropertyChanged("WifeCount"); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class OptionValue
    {
        string _mDisplay;
        object _mValue;

        public string Display { get { return _mDisplay; } set { _mDisplay = value; } }

        public object Value { get { return _mValue; } set { _mValue = value; } }

        public OptionValue(string display, object value)
        {
            _mDisplay = display;
            _mValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Adding an event handler to the ComboBox seems to work:

```
void _mComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var binding = (sender as Control).DataBindings["SelectedValue"];
      if (binding != null)
          binding.WriteValue();

      this.Text = string.Format("SelectedValue: {0}; WifeCount: {1}", _mComboBox.SelectedValue, _mEntity.WifeCount);
}
```

Comment: I think the more pressing question is _WifeCount_?

Comment: lols.. I just randomly choose a variable. Supposed to be LifeCount but I am conditioned to rename everything on SO.

Comment: Which direction is it not working?

Comment: For me it's setting the the value at the Entity. i.e. clicking the assign button.

Comment: @AaronMcIver wow.. nice upvotes. but people should not just come here to check on wife count!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that in order to have two-way binding, you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the element that is in the binding list. The reason is that the BindingList that's being used as the datasource doesn't know when any of the elements have changed unless the elements pass on that information. However, it can still pass on events relating to items being added and removed (assuming you specify AllowRemove/AllowNew properties to true) because that event is in the realm of the list, not the individual elements.

*Edit:* Bah! Jumped the gun and didn't read the question/problem thoroughly. Here's the issue, adding databindings apparently defaults to a one way binding (initial bind value ONLY). What you need to do is specify the DataSourceUpdateMode when adding the databinding to the combobox:

```
_mComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _mEntity, "WifeCount", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Just tested this out with everything else staying the same and it worked. Let me know!

*Edit: So it isn't working (I wasn't clearing the list), and I figured out why.* So this is what I'm noticing. For some reason, the binding context for the entity is getting cleared anytime the underlying datasource is getting changed. Not entirely sure why, but I have most definitely found that that's the issue. The way I found out was adding a watch to the binding context of the _mComboBox for the entity: `_mComboBox.BindingContext[_mEntity]` and keeping track of the Bindings count. As soon as a new item gets added to the _mBindingList, it seems to muck with the internal databindings of the ComboBox, which ultimately drops the binding for the Entity.WifeCount -> ComboBox.SelectedValue binding we setup. Tried various things, but I'm not entirely sure WHY the PropertyManager drops the binding when the underlying datasource changes.

Comment: I haven't try this, but why are you implementing in OptionValue rather than Entity?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I have updated the OP full code listing to better reflect my actual code which HAD implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. The updated problem is in the assign button click handler, which now has the BindingList.Clear() and re-populate values.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the question thoroughly (would've caught it right away if I did). Didn't realize that you had a separate entity that was going to be firing off the property changes, and that the OptionValue class was just there for presentation purposes only. I've removed the unnecessary code and added my final solution, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: "So it isn't working (I wasn't clearing the list), and I figured out why" yes, really strange and frustrating!

Comment: This has been bothering me since yesterday, and I have an inkling that it has to do with binding the ComboBox's "SelectedValue" property to the underlying BindingSource CurrancyManager state (the CurrentItem) when the list changes (ensures the binding is properly bound to the DisplayMember/ValueMember). Tried looking through the source code, but for some reason it won't let me debug into the .NET source (even though I have everything setup for it).

Comment: Same here. Setting `_mBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false` before `.Clear()` and `_mBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true` after `_mEntity.WifeCount = 3M;` seems to work although there is no telling if there are any more hidden problems.

Comment: Update: Adding event handler to write value seems to work (see OP edit)

Comment: Update: Just found an interesting StackOverflow article that actually explains a little of why this happens (though the question is for WPF). I have a feeling the same issue is happening, where SetBinding is called somewhere as a side-effect of adding to the underlying collection, and the BindingContext doesn't necessarily know which one to continue using anymore. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761531/chain-of-databinding

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are trying to do, I think this is probably a workable solution:

Two-way binding is fine as you have it but clearing the datasource of the combobox kills the databindings as well.  If you are going to be changing the binding list you should probably re-bind any time the datasource changes :

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // combo box datasource binding
    PrepareComboBox(_mComboBox, _mBindingList);

    // entity data binding
    UpdateBindings();

    base.OnLoad(e);
}


public void UpdateBindings()
{
    _mComboBox.DataBindings.Clear();
    if (_mBindingList.Count != 0) _mComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _mEntity, "WifeCount");
}

void _mAssignButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mBindingList.Clear();          
    foreach (var o in _mCacheList) _mBindingList.Add(o);
    // UPDATE BINDINGS HERE - Only do this if changing the binding source
    UpdateBindings();

    _mEntity.WifeCount = 3M;

    this.Text = string.Format("SelectedValue: {0}; WifeCount: {1}", _mComboBox.SelectedValue, _mEntity.WifeCount);
}
```

Comment: The binding from source to combo box also updates when the INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented as described by SPFiredrake. My problem is somehow modifying the _mBindingList items breaks it. I want to be able to modify the list and then assign a value on Entity.

Comment: I tested the method above with your added code (_mCacheList, etc) and it works...have you tried it?  Where does it break? How?

Comment: With the _mBindingList.Clear() and .Add(), run the program > select two > click check > form.Text show 2-2 > then click assign > form.Text show 1-3. The desired output should be 3-3. If the Clear() and Add() are commented out, we get the desired 3-3. So obviously the Clear() and Add() did something strange to the binding. But what is it? And how to overcome?

Comment: added to my answer above - you still need to connect an event handler in Form1

Comment: Rebinding every time is overkill. When creating a two-way binding, you're telling the bound control that it needs to listen for changes (which is fired off using the PropertyChanged event). Imagine how convoluted code would be for DataGridViews anytime an entity changed... It's impractical.

Comment: updated answer - this is tested and works.  Rebinding is required here if the binding source changes.  I agree it is inefficient to link it to the propertyChanged event of the entity but it must be done manually when changing the binding source.  You could probably also link it to the ListChanged event of the BindingList if you catch against binding to a source with no state reflected in the list (ie: during edits)

Comment: @J... Thanks for you help, but although your method works, i consider it messy because calling update bindings in the logic layer feels bad. I may be able to hook it to BindingList.ListChanged event but still it will be fired multiple times. The pressing question now is why it doesn't happen to ComboBox.Text binding (See updated OP). I can't seem to find a reference that addresses this. I will continue to try this problem and mark yours as answer at the end if all else fails.

Comment: I agree the approach is kludgy, but it was just to demonstrate the point.  If you just hook to ListChanged, as you say, it fires multiple times and if you are still databound you get index exceptions on changes which empty the bindingsource, etc.  Better, perhaps, to wrap bindinglist changes separately with UpdateBindings.

Comment: As for why the binding to .Text does not break my best guess would be that .Text is a single field which is always present.  "SelectedValue" maps to an enum of changing size - probably it is the case that when you clear the underlying BindingList there is no longer a mapping for the DataBinding to link to and it breaks.  With .Text that field is always there and accessible.

Comment: In fact, if you do link UpdateBindings to ListChanged you'll see an exception thrown on BindingList.Clear() because your combo.SelectedValue will have nothing in the BindingList (empty) to link to.  This is probably thrown silently when a DataBinding is still alive and it kills it.  If you try to re-bind with nothing to bind to, however, you see the exception.