# Exception not thrown on DataBinding invalid dataMember

Tags: c#, data-binding

While trying to solve a two-way data binding problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973682/why-does-the-combobox-selectedvalue-databinding-context-gets-cleared-when-bindin), I found that the following does not throw an invalid member exception, which if I recall correctly, it should. MSDN also documents the existence of this Exception [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2.aspx), but why doesn't it throw?

```
namespace EnumDataBinding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            ComboBox box = new ComboBox();

            // EXPECT: DataMember not found exception
            // RESULT: Exception not thrown!
            box.DataBindings.Add("Text", new Entity(), "asdhjgfjhrt");
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }


    public class Entity
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't add `ComboBox` into container (Form).

```
public Form1()
 {
  ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
  Controls.Add(box);
  // EXPECT: DataMember not found exception
  // RESULT: Exception not thrown!
  box.DataBindings.Add("Text", new Entity(), "asdhjgfjhrt");
 }
```